# How to handle input in Monogame

Tags: xna, monogame, input

I've just switched over to MonoGame from XNA. Since MonoGame is supposed to have the same API (implying that any copied code should work as usual), I've run into a strange issue- input doesn't seem to be handled through MonoGame.

When I tried to fix any missing "using" directives in that class, it automatically added `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input` which implies that there's no MonoGame equivalent.

Googling the issue had no success- all the tutorials I found for MonoGame said to use XNA's input.

Is there a MonoGame equivalent for handling input, or do I just need to use XNA for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MonoGame intentionally uses the same namespaces as XNA as required to make it a drop in replacement.

For Example look at the MonoGame [VS2010 Template](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/ProjectTemplates/VisualStudio2010/Windows/Game1.cs)

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
```

The `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input` uses MonoGame if Monogame is included as a reference; alternatively, it uses XNA if XNA is included as a reference. If you have both frameworks referenced it would throw an error and force you to disambiguate.